# Adding spaces within the (string) elements of an array

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x

Is there a way to create a program, in python 3.5, that could make every character in an array be their own element within the same array?

For example:

`character = [ "#$@#%" , "%#@#%" ]`

Becomes this when ran through the program

`character = [ "#", "$" , "@" , "#" , "%" , "%" , "#" , "@" , "#" , "%"]`

Thank you, any help at all is appreciated

Comment: Sorry I submitted it prematurely

Comment: This question lacks research. Welcome to StackOverflow, do research, try something. If there is something you don't understand or the code doesn't work then post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each string into a list, then chain the lists:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(map(list, character)))
#['#', '$', '@', '#', '%', '%', '#', '@', '#', '%']
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, this solved it directly!

Comment: Do you actually prefer that over `list(''.join(character))`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Not necessarily. But both solutions work, though yours is somewhat faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
m=len(character)
for i in range(m):
    character+=list(character[0])
    character.pop(0)
print character
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!